# Create new row for each conditional value in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create new row for each null value. For example:

**Data Origen Table:** this table have two null values (adidas, nike), i want to create new for for each id_brand when id_brand is null

Formula
***count id_brand with null value*** * ***id_brand with not null value***

6 new rows = 2 null value * 3 not null value

Table

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
| id_category | description | id_brand | value |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
|           5 | adidas      |          |   100 |
|           5 | nike        |          |    65 |
|           5 | samsung     |        1 |    40 |
|           5 | coca-cola   |        2 |    15 |
|           5 | puma        |        3 |    70 |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
```

The data table that i expect, the current rows and new 6 rows (each for id_brand with not null value)

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
| id_category | description | id_brand | value |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
|           5 | adidas      |          |   100 |
|           5 | nike        |          |    65 |
|           5 | samsung     |        1 |    40 |
|           5 | coca-cola   |        2 |    15 |
|           5 | puma        |        3 |    70 |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
|           5 | adidas      |        1 |   100 |
|           5 | nike        |        1 |    65 |
|           5 | adidas      |        2 |   100 |
|           5 | nike        |        2 |    65 |
|           5 | adidas      |        3 |   100 |
|           5 | nike        |        3 |    65 |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
```

How can I accomplish something like this in Sql?

Comment: Can you please explain your logic for wanting this behavior, I see no reason for this.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? This can be done with a cross join, but it seems a really weird requirement.

Comment: What I would do would be to create a sequence like adding by default value in the table.

Comment: @Esteban a sequence won't do what is requested here.

Comment: @LuisCazares I'm using DevExpress MVC Reports. For the design of my report, the data must be created in that way.

Comment: @LuisCazares why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's only for a report, and you're absolutely sure that this is required, this can be accomplished with a simple CROSS JOIN. I'm adding sample data in a consumable format, which is the best way to post it if you're asking for help in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData(
    id_category int,
    description varchar(100),
    id_brand    int,
    value       int
)
INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES
    (5, 'adidas   ', NULL, 100),
    (5, 'nike     ', NULL,  65),
    (5, 'samsung  ', 1,  40),
    (5, 'coca-cola', 2,  15),
    (5, 'puma     ', 3,  70);

SELECT d.id_category, 
       d.description,
       b.id_brand,
       d.value
FROM SampleData d
CROSS JOIN SampleData b
WHERE b.id_brand IS NOT NULL
AND d.id_brand IS NULL
ORDER BY id_brand, description;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, it works like a charm 